# Outlook 2007 Add-In : Reuse built-in 'To...' control at my Form Region (WinForm)

Tags: c#, winforms, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-object-model

Is it possible to add **'To...'** 'Outlook.OlkTextBox' [OlkTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.olktextbox.aspx) control at my WinForm (form region), so it will work like outlook build-in (I don't want to create my own copy of outlook address email input)?

If yes, could you somebody post a code sample?

Thanks!

P.S. *Microsoft Office Outlook Text Box Control* equals Outlook.OlkTextBox.
I tried to use design mode (Visual Studio Tool Box with added COM component), but getting strange error while moving it at win form:

*Microsoft Visual Studio
Failed to create component 'AxHost'.  The error message follows:
 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))
   at System.Windows.Forms.Design.DocumentDesigner.AxToolboxItem.CreateComponentsCore(IDesignerHost host)
   at System.Drawing.Design.ToolboxItem.CreateComponentsCore(IDesignerHost host, IDictionary defaultValues)
   at System.Drawing.Design.ToolboxItem.CreateComponents(IDesignerHost host, IDictionary defaultValues)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Design.OleDragDropHandler.CreateTool(ToolboxItem tool, Control parent, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, Boolean hasLocation, Boolean hasSize, ToolboxSnapDragDropEventArgs e)'*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that this is impossible, because 'To...' control is COM based and designed to work with COM form region (internal Outlook form region) (NOT WINFORM!)

Will work for Outlook INTERNAL Form Region only:

---

*Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlkTextBox 
dynamicTextBox = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlkTextBox();
dynamic form = this.OutlookFormRegion.Form;
form.Controls.Add("Outlook.OlkTextBox", dynamicTextBox, true);
dynamicTextBox.Text = "Hello world!";*

Comment: Result: I decided to implement my own 'To...' user control using RichTextBox and button (with standard outlook dialogue shown on click).  Main idea: 1) attach recipient changed event to logic and 2) create mapping between recipient characters (start/end) and real recipient index and collection. Then track all delete, selection and son on to emulate all operation. Most complex was add (with popup), so temporary i had skipped this subtask.